# Deleting of rows causing #REF errors

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013, excel-indirect

I have a worksheet that users input employee names and date of birth for various calculations. A few users are deleting rows that are causing #REF errors with the calculations and I am looking for a solution around it. Indirect or Offset are options I am considering to solve the issue.

Here is my data in Column A:

1. Bobby Jones
2. Richard Haden
3. Scott White
4. Vanessa Anderson

Column H starting at cell 100 I have a calculation to trim the first name:

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,1)),"")
```

1. Jones
2. Haden
3. White
4. Anderson

My question is if a user deletes Richard Haden for example, cell H101 produces a #REF error. How do I add a Indirect or Offset function to the formulas in Column H to eliminate the possibility of REF errors when a row is deleted?

Results I am looking for with the above scenario:

1. Jones
2. White
3. Anderson

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `INDEX` to return the cell at the row number junction in the column.

For example, `INDEX($A:$A,1)` will always return the value in the first cell of column 1.  `INDEX($A:$A,2)` will always return the second cell, etc.

So:
`=IFERROR(MID(INDEX($A:$A,1),FIND(" ",INDEX($A:$A,1))+1,LEN(INDEX($A:$A,1))),"")`
 will show the new first row if the existing one is deleted.

**Note:**
I usually use `=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1))` rather than `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1))` but no idea which is faster.

**Note 2:** Use `ROW()-99` rather than 1 in H100 to return the correct row number.
`=IFERROR(MID(INDEX($A:$A,ROW()-99),FIND(" ",INDEX($A:$A,ROW()-99))+1,LEN(INDEX($A:$A,ROW()-99))),"")`

**Note 3:** `INDEX` is non-volatile while `OFFSET` is (recalculates *every* time).

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - Does Note 2 formula have to be in a different tab?  I currently have the names and formulas on the same tab so if an employee is deleted, than the ROW()-99 part of the formula selects the wrong cell.  H 100-99 = 1, but if I delete a row, than H100 turns to 99 and 99-99=0.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that bit.  Yep, will break the formula as it tries to reference row 0.  You don't need to have the formula on another sheet, just the row reference.  Change each instance of `ROW()` to look at row 100 in a sheet that isn't going to have rows deleted: `ROW(Sheet2!A100)`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - the formula works exactly how I want it to, thank you!  Now onto updating the rest of my formulas...ugh!

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

First step: Add header cell to you name list (cell A1) for example "Names"

Second step: Add counter in column F from `F100` (counter i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4)

Use offset (from cell H100):

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT(OFFSET($A$1,F100;0),LEN(OFFSET($A$1,F100;0))-FIND(" ",OFFSET($A$1,F100;0),1)),"")
```

Quick reference how to use `OFFSET`: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-offset-function. Logic behind: as you have counter you will always get cell X rows below your header. Deleting rows will not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

A problem you will see with this solution is that the trim-rows creep up as other rows are deleted.  This is why I prefer to have calculations hidden on a seperate tab.

However, you can combine `OFFSET` with `ROW` to say "The row that is as far from POSITION1 as I am from POSITION2".  If we make POSTION1 = `$A$1` (which means it will fail if row 1 is deleted - best to have a header row!) and POSITION2 = `$H$100`, then you can say

```
OFFSET($A$1,ROW()-ROW($H$100),0)
```

**Some examples**

> Cell H100: Row() - Row($H$100) = 100 - 100 = 0 | `OFFSET($A$1, 0, 0)` = A1
>
> Cell H101: Row() - Row($H$100) = 101 - 100 = 1 | `OFFSET($A$1, 1, 0)` = A2
>
> Cell H110: Row() - Row($H$100) = 110 - 100 = 10 | `OFFSET($A$1, 10, 0)` = A11

Now, let's delete row 2.  This shifts H100 to H99, H101 to H100 and H110 to H109:

> Cell H99: Row() - Row($H$99) = 99 - 99 = 0 | `OFFSET($A$1, 0, 0)` = A1
>
> Cell H100: Row() - Row($H$99) = 100 - 99 = 1 | `OFFSET($A$1, 1, 0)` = A2
>
> Cell H109: Row() - Row($H$99) = 109 - 99 = 10 | `OFFSET($A$1, 10, 0)` = A11

(The other problem I can see with your formula is people with two 2 forenames, such as racing driver "Juan Pablo Montoya Roldán" - his forename is "Juan Pablo", his surname is "Montoya Roldán")